# Why is the styling with Expo working on web but not on mobile

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm making a mobile app using Expo, when I go on the web interface for the app which I used to test when coding, it works just fine but when I try the app on a mobile phone the styling is all messed up.

for example this is the Signup page which also doesn't work:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';
import Svg, { Defs, G, Path, LinearGradient, Stop } from 'react-native-svg';

export default class Signup extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ImageBackground style={styles.container} source={require('../../assets/background_image.jpg')}>
                <Svg style={styles.logo} width="60" height="60" viewBox="0 0 60 60">
                    <Defs>
                        <LinearGradient id="a" x1="50%" x2="50%" y1="99.9%" y2="-.1%">
                            <Stop offset="0%" stop-color="#AA8436" />
                            <Stop offset="100%" stop-color="#EFE296" />
                        </LinearGradient>
                    </Defs>
                    <G fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                        <Path fill="#FFF" d="M40.126 2.038C28.607-2.512 15.51.716 7.34 10.118c-8.169 9.403-9.667 22.975-3.75 33.973a9.802 9.802 0 0 0 3.387 3.63c8.982 5.76 20.705 4.44 28.22-3.177a13.29 13.29 0 0 0 3.531-6.505.907.907 0 0 0-.134-.796.882.882 0 0 0-.712-.363.798.798 0 0 0-.647.302 11.758 11.758 0 0 1-16.773 0 18.272 18.272 0 0 1-5.226-12.709 18.484 18.484 0 0 1 5.774-13.312 27.742 27.742 0 0 1 8.461-5.552A26.625 26.625 0 0 1 39.778 3.6h.05a.798.798 0 0 0 .803-.652.807.807 0 0 0-.505-.909z" />
                        <Path fill="url(#a)" d="M55.76 16.014a9.646 9.646 0 0 0-3.322-3.578c-8.817-5.677-20.324-4.376-27.7 3.132a12.88 12.88 0 0 0-3.467 6.461.886.886 0 0 0 .44.956.855.855 0 0 0 1.026-.16c.135-.145.282-.278.44-.398a11.535 11.535 0 0 1 16.072.398c3.307 3.333 5.14 7.889 5.081 12.624-.05 4.949-2.099 9.658-5.668 13.022-4.981 4.775-11.573 7.425-18.418 7.405h-.049a.841.841 0 0 0-.803.699c-.071.397.142.79.51.942C31.22 62 44.085 58.809 52.104 49.529c8.02-9.28 9.482-22.669 3.662-33.514h-.006z" />
                    </G>
                </Svg>

                <Text style={styles.slogan}>Créer, organiser vos
                formations et évenements.
                </Text>

                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => {this.props.navigation.navigate('Proceed')}}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>S’inscrire</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

                <Text style={styles.loginAskText}>Vous êtes dèjà membre ?</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.props.navigation.navigate('Login')}}>
                    <Text style={styles.loginText}>Se connecter</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </ImageBackground>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        flex: 1,
        alignSelf: 'stretch'
    },
    logo: {
        width: 60,
        height: 60,
        marginTop: '10%'
    },
    slogan: {
        width: 285,
        height: 64,
        fontFamily: "HelveticaNeue",
        fontSize: 24,
        fontWeight: "normal",
        fontStyle: "normal",
        lineHeight: 32,
        letterSpacing: 0,
        textAlign: "center",
        color: "#ffffff",
        marginTop: '3%',
    },
    button: {
        width: 294,
        height: 58,
        borderRadius: 4,
        backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
        marginTop: '20.6%',
        paddingTop: '1.5%'
    },
    buttonText: {
        fontFamily: "HelveticaNeue",
        fontSize: 16,
        fontWeight: "normal",
        fontStyle: "normal",
        letterSpacing: 0,
        textAlign: "center",
        color: "#22386c"
    },
    loginAskText: {
        marginTop: `2%`,
        width: 159,
        height: 16,
        fontFamily: "HelveticaNeue",
        fontSize: 14,
        fontWeight: "normal",
        fontStyle: "normal",
        letterSpacing: 0,
        textAlign: "center",
        color: "#ffffff"
    },
    loginText: {
        width: 102,
        height: 19,
        fontFamily: "HelveticaNeue",
        fontSize: 16,
        fontWeight: "bold",
        fontStyle: "normal",
        letterSpacing: 0,
        textAlign: "center",
        color: "#ffffff",
        margin: '10%'
    }
});
```

for example when I just tried to run this app on my phone, the design was centered but there was no background image, and all the elements were like only showing half, the other half was hidden at the top.

Comment: You mean you ran it as a simulator in case of web? Location can be different because cell phones have different sizes.

Comment: How can I make it flexible on any phone then?

Comment: Can you show the result screen when you are a simulator?

Comment: [Screenshoot](https://ibb.co/KzpqdDz)